# is the Chunked encoding working correctly?

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with chunked encoding. Here's a sample code:

```
opts={
     hostname: "httpbin.org",
     path: '/post',
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain", // should default to chunked
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    },
};
var req = http.request(opts, function(res){
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on("data", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
req.write("hello");
req.end();

Data returned from httpbin:


{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",

}
```

Noticed that the data is empty.

However, once I add `'Content-Length': 5,`  to `opts.headers`, chunked encoding is disabled and the data becomes "hello" as expected.

What's wrong with chunked encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/httpbin/issues/102) with httpbin. You're not doing anything wrong client-side.